# which cast is faster static_cast<int> () or int()

Tags: c++, c, performance

Try to see which cast is faster (not necessary better): new c++ case or old fashion C style cast.  Any ideas?

Comment: you could always write a benchmark script.  Just do 10 million static_cast and 10 million int cast, and see which one takes longer.  my *guess* is that they will compile to the same assembly instruction.

Comment: Disregarding the fact that they almost certainly compile the same on all compilers, why would this be important?  Unless you have known performance issues, you write to be clear and avoid harder-to-read microoptimizations that are probably pointless anyway.  Use static_cast<int>().

Comment: C style casts are defined in terms of c++ style casts (and c style casts can cast to private bases...). So they are actually pretty equivalent. no-one has a performance boost over the other one.

Comment: For what it's worth, `int(10.4)` isn't a C-style cast, as that's not valid C (it calls the function `int()` with an argument). The "C-style" cast is `(int)10.4`.

Comment: @Chris: true, but the function-style cast is *exactly equivalent* to the C-style cast.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There should be no difference at all if you compare `int()` to *equivalent* functionality of `static_cast<int>()`.

Using VC2008:

```
    double d = 10.5;
013A13EE  fld         qword ptr [__real@4025000000000000 (13A5840h)] 
013A13F4  fstp        qword ptr [d] 
    int x = int(d);
013A13F7  fld         qword ptr [d] 
013A13FA  call        @ILT+215(__ftol2_sse) (13A10DCh) 
013A13FF  mov         dword ptr [x],eax 
    int y = static_cast<int>(d);
013A1402  fld         qword ptr [d] 
013A1405  call        @ILT+215(__ftol2_sse) (13A10DCh) 
013A140A  mov         dword ptr [y],eax
```

Obviously, it is 100% the same!

Comment: This doesn't look sexy to me :) A sexy one would use SSE instructuions without involving the FPU at all :) (I thought SSE was used by default in VC already).

Comment: @AndreyT It does :) the code in the answer was produced in debugging mode. If you try to compile it with optimizations, it does use SSE instructions.

Comment: -1(if I could). It is not obviously. Your answer proves that it is the same only in certain version of VS2008.

Comment: Is it platform dependent? Does different compiler may treat these two types of casting differently?

Answer (score 4):

No difference whatsoever.

When it comes to such basic constructs as a single cast, once two constructs have the same semantic meaning, their performace will be perfectly identical, and the machine code generated for these constructs will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the actual result is implementation defined. You should check it in your version of compiler. But I believe that it will give the same result in most modern compilers. And in C++ you shouldn't use C-cast, instead use [C++ casts](https://web.archive.org/web/20100412112440/http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds3-1/ovp3-1.html) - it will allow you to find errors at compile time.

Comment: Performance issues are not implementation-defined (in fact the standard doesn't mandate any performance at all, other than big-O for container operations)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the assembly using each method. If it differs use a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

They are same as it is resolved during compile time itself and there is no runtime overhead. Even if there was some difference I really wouldn't bother too much about these tiny (not even micro) optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

As most people say one hopes these should be the same speed, although you're at the mercy of your compiler... and that's not always a very happy situation. Read on for war stories.

Depending on your compiler and the particular model of processor core which the program executes on the speed of `float f; int i(f);`, `float f; int i = (int)f;` and `float f; int i = static_cast<int>(f);` and their ilk (including variations involving double, long and unsigned types) can be atrociously slow - an order of magnitude worse than you expect. The compiler may emit instructions altering internal processor modes causing instruction pipelines to be thrown away. This is, in effect, a bug in the optimization element of the compiler. I've seen cases where one suffers the sort 40-clock-cycle costs mentioned in [this analysis](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/why-you-should-never-cast-floats-to-ints/), at which point you have a major, unexpected and irritating performance bottleneck with AFAIK no entirely pleasing, robust, generic solution. There are alternatives involving assembler but AFAIK they do not round floating point to integer the same way as the casts do. If anyone knows any better I am interested. I'm hoping this issue is/will shortly be confined to legacy compilers/hardware but you need your wits about you.

P.S. I can't reach that link because my firewall blocks it as games-related but [a Google cache of it](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RX4k8SSUCv8J:assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/why-you-should-never-cast-floats-to-ints/%20&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) suffices to demonstrate that its author knows more about it than I do.

Answer (score -2):

When you choice makes little difference to the code, I'd pick the one which looks more familiar to later programmers. Making code easier to understand by others is always worth considering. In this case, I'd stick to `int(…)` for that reason.

Comment: Why would you assume that int(...) will be more familiar, though? It actually appears not to be valid in C, being perhaps rather a "pseudo-constructor" call of C++. - Also, by not being explicit about the type of cast, why should it make code easier to understand?

Comment: Casts are nothing to be toyed with and should therefore be easy to spot. That's what the C++-style casts are.